# Add text to ggplot with facetted densities

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I'm encountering a problem when trying to make a density plot with ggplot.
The data look a bit like in the example here.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)
mms <- data.frame(deliciousness = rnorm(100),
                  type=sample(as.factor(c("peanut", "regular")), 100, replace=TRUE),
                  color=sample(as.factor(c("red", "green", "yellow", "brown")), 100, replace=TRUE))


mms.cor <- ddply(.data=mms, .(type, color), summarize, n=paste("n =", length(deliciousness)))

plot <- ggplot(data=mms, aes(x=deliciousness)) + geom_density() + facet_grid(type ~ color) + geom_text(data=mms.cor, aes(x=1.8, y=5, label=n), colour="black", inherit.aes=FALSE, parse=FALSE)
```

Labelling each facet with the labels work quite well unless the scales for each facet vary. Does anyone have an idea how I could achieve putting the labels at the same location when the scales per facet differ?

Best,
daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
plot <- ggplot(data=mms, aes(x=deliciousness)) +
  geom_density(aes(y=..scaled..)) + facet_grid(type ~ color) +
  geom_text(data=mms.cor, aes(x=1.2, y=1.2, label=n), colour="black")
plot
```

[image]

There is a way to get the limits set internally by ggplot with `scales="free"`, but it involves hacking the `grob` (graphics object). Since you seem to want the density plots to have equal height (???), you can do that with `aes(y=..scaled...)`. Then setting the location for the labels is straightforward.

**EDIT** (Response to OP's comment)

This is what I meant by hacking the `grob`. Note that this takes advantage of the *internal structure* used by `gglpot`. The problem is that this could change at any time with a new version (and in fact it is already different from older versions). So there is no guarantee this code will work in the future.

```
plot <- ggplot(data=mms, aes(x=deliciousness)) +
  geom_density() + 
  facet_grid(type ~ color, scales="free")
panels <- ggplot_build(plot)[["panel"]]
limits <- do.call(rbind,lapply(panels$ranges,
                               function(range)c(range$x.range,range$y.range)))
colnames(limits) <- c("x.lo","x.hi","y.lo","y.hi")
mms.cor <- cbind(mms.cor,limits)
plot + 
  geom_text(data=mms.cor, aes(x=x.hi, y=y.hi, label=n), hjust=1,colour="black")
```

[image]

The basic idea is to generate `plot` *without the text*, then build the graphics object using `ggplot_build(plot)`. From this we can extract the x- and y-limits, and bind those to the labels in your `mms.cor` data frame. Now render the plot with the text, using these limits.

Note that the plots are different from my earlier answer because you did not use `set.seed(...)` in your code to generate the dataset (and I forgot to add it...).

Comment: In your solution, the scale is the same for every facet. What I would like to have is different scales (scales="free") for every facet and then to place the text at the same position in every facet. So I have different heights and widths. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you're last post does the job. Build the figure, extract the limits and use them with a new data frame containing these limits, a column with the names of the facets and the text I want to add. Works great, thanks for the solution

Comment: A very nice solution, which also works, if facet scales are set to "free".