# Put labels on pie ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, label

My df looks like:

```
1   with score
125 without score
```

I'd like to make piechart in ggplot:

```
ggplot(data = df_pp, aes(x = "", y = Number/sum(Number),fill =     PolyPhen_score)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_polar(theta='y')  +
ggtitle("Variants with PolyPhen score and without PolyPhen score") + 
scale_y_continuous(labels  = percent) + labs(x = "", y = "") +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white')) + 
geom_text(aes(label = paste(round(Number/sum(Number)*100),"%")),vjust = 5)
```

But my labels 1% and 99% are overlapped on the piechart.

If I add this code, it doesn't help:

```
geom_text(aes(y=Number/2 + c(0,cumsum(Number)[-length(Number)]), label = percent(Number/100)), size=5)
```

Comment: Add data to your post, `dput(df_pp)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe these other Stackoverflow questions can help you:

1. [ggplot, facet, piechart: placing text in the middle of piechart slices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22804400/2204410)
2. [R + ggplot2 => add labels on facet pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803460/r-ggplot2-add-labels-on-facet-pie-chart)

I did few tests on my machine with some random data and I tried with this:

```
geom_text(aes(x = 1.7, y=cumsum(Number/sum(Number)) - Number/sum(Number)/2, label = paste(round(Number/sum(Number)*100),"%")), size = 6)
```

`X` is the distance of labels from the center of the pie. `x = 1.7` gives me a nice result with my data in RStudio, but probably you will need different values.