# Adding percentage labels on pie chart in R

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, pie-chart

My data frame looks like

```
df
   Group   value
1 Positive    52
2 Negative   239
3 Neutral     9
```

I would like to make a pie chart of the data frame using ggplot.

```
pie <- ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=value, fill=Group)) +
       geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
       coord_polar("y", start=0)
```

This is my pie chart.

[image]

But when I try to add percentage labels on the chart

```
pie <- ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=value, fill=Group)) +
       geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
       coord_polar("y", start=0) +
       geom_text(aes(y = value/2 + c(0, cumsum(value)[-length(value)]),
                 label = percent(value/300 )), size=5)
```

This is my result.

[image]

I have already seen many same question as mine,i.e  [R + ggplot2 => add labels on facet pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803460/r-ggplot2-add-labels-on-facet-pie-chart)  and the solutions are not helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @hrbrmstr a waffle chart would be better.  But to answer the original question... your problem comes from the order in which the wedges are drawn, which will default to alphabetical.  As you calculate where to place the labels based on the ordering in your data frame, this works out wrong.

As a general principle of readability, do all the fancy calculations of labels and positions they go before the actual code drawing the graphic.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap) # for theme_nothing
df <- data.frame(value = c(52, 239, 9),
                 Group = c("Positive", "Negative", "Neutral")) %>%
   # factor levels need to be the opposite order of the cumulative sum of the values
   mutate(Group = factor(Group, levels = c("Neutral", "Negative", "Positive")),
          cumulative = cumsum(value),
          midpoint = cumulative - value / 2,
          label = paste0(Group, " ", round(value / sum(value) * 100, 1), "%"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = 1, weight = value, fill = Group)) +
   geom_bar(width = 1, position = "stack") +
   coord_polar(theta = "y") +
   geom_text(aes(x = 1.3, y = midpoint, label = label)) +
   theme_nothing()
```

[image]

Comment: I think the percentage labels for Positive and Negative are reversed in your graphic.

Comment: thanks @jazzurro, i've now corrected it.  The code was all fine, I just had the wrong numbers in the original data frame.  If the OP had included a reproducible example I wouldn't have made that typo.

Comment: It's working. Thank you @PeterEllis , you saved my life :)

Answer (score 15):

How about:

```
vals <- c(239, 52, 9)
val_names <- sprintf("%s (%s)", c("Negative", "Positive", "Neutral"), scales::percent(round(vals/sum(vals), 2)))
names(vals) <- val_names

waffle::waffle(vals) +
  ggthemes::scale_fill_tableau(name=NULL)
```

[image]

instead?

It's "fresher" than a pie chart and you aren't really gaining anything with the level of precision you have/want on those pie labels now.

Comment: Agree. but the problem is that this chart is from my final year project and i used pie chart when i submitted the project thesis. now i can not change the charts.
it was working fine back then i don't what just happened with the code. 
Thanks anyway

Comment: Guy asked for pie chart not fancy chart

Answer (score 8):

For example, I create a dataframe e3 with 400 vehicles:

```
e3 <- data.frame(400)
e3 <- rep( c("car", "truck", "other", "bike", "suv"), c(60, 120, 20, 50, 150))
```

Since pie charts are especially useful for proportions, let's have a look on the proportions of our vehicles, than we will report on the graph in this case:

```
paste(prop.table(table(e3))*100, "%", sep = "")
[1] "15%"   "5%"    "30%"   "12.5%" "37.5%"
```

Then you can draw your pie chart,

```
pie(table(e3), labels = paste(round(prop.table(table(e3))*100), "%", sep = ""), 
col = heat.colors(5), main = "Vehicles proportions - n: 400")
```

[image]

Comment: Uops, I forgot about ggplo2, sorry!

Answer (score 6):

Here is an idea matching the order of groups in the pie chart and the order of labels. I sorted the data in descending order by `value`. I also calculated the percentage in advance. When I drew the ggplot figure, I specified the order of `Group` in the order in `mydf` (i.e., Negative, Positive, and Neutral) using `fct_inorder()`. When `geom_label_repel()` added labels to the pie, the order of label was identical to that of the pie.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(forcats)
library(scales)

mydf %>%
arrange(desc(value)) %>%
mutate(prop = percent(value / sum(value))) -> mydf 

pie <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = fct_inorder(Group))) +
       geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
       coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
       geom_label_repel(aes(label = prop), size=5, show.legend = F, nudge_x = 1) +
       guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Group"))
```

[image]

DATA

```
mydf <- structure(list(Group = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Negative", 
"Neutral", "Positive"), class = "factor"), value = c(52L, 239L, 
9L)), .Names = c("Group", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my example, using only the basic R code. Hope it help.

*Take iris for example*

```
attach(iris)
```

*check the the ratio of iris$Species*

```
a<- table(iris$Species)
class(a)
```

*then convert table format into matrix in order to use rowname code*

```
a_mat<- as.matrix(a)
a_mat
```

*calculate the ratio of each Species*

```
a_ratio<- a_mat[,1]/sum(a_mat[,1])*100
a_ratio
```

*since each Species accounts for 0.33333 (i.e. 33.33333%), I just want 2 decimal places by using signif()*

```
a_ratio<- signif(a_ratio,3)
a_ratio
```

*basic pie chart code of R base*

```
pie(a_ratio,labels=rownames(a_mat))
```

*further add ratio values to labels by using paste()*

```
pie(a_ratio,labels=paste(rownames(a_mat),c("33%","33%","34%")))
```

[final pie chart, please click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VITAc.jpg)