# Pie chart custom color palette percent

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, palette

I have to use a color palette given by my organisation.
But I have errors message.

```
DT <- data.table(induse = c("C29", "P7","TOTAL"), values = c(570,100,600))
paletteEcoFin <- c("9A5EA6", "E5C473", "B98B50", "61276D", "2E368F","D8C5E0", "0000FF", "800080")
pie = ggplot(DT, aes(x="", y=values, fill=induse)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1)
pie = pie + coord_polar("y", start=0) 
+  scale_fill_manual(values=paletteEcoFin)
```

Error when I try to view pie is

```
  Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name 'B98B50'
```

Furthermore, how can I get automatic % calculated and showed on the pie chart?
Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to add the ‘#’ in front of the hex codes. For the % labels, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338757/adding-percentage-labels-on-pie-chart-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider to change first three values of `paletteEcoFin` vector (i.e. adding `#`, as a regular hexcolor):

```
paletteEcoFin <- c("#9A5EA6", "#E5C473", "#B98B50", "61276D", "2E368F","D8C5E0", "0000FF", "800080")

ggplot(DT, aes(x="", y=values, fill=induse)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=paletteEcoFin)
```

[image]

Comment: It answers the first part of the question.Thanks for this. But for the second part, how to represent in the graph the % and not the values, like 570/870 in %, 100/870 and 200/870 in % ?