# ggplot - use pie chart to visualize number of items in each group in terms of percentages - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, percentage, facet

I want to create two pie chart to show number of people in each level of the factor variable. However, I want to obtain two pie charts, one for two groups.

Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- filter(diamonds, color %in% c("E", "D"))

ggplot(df,aes(x= "", fill=cut)) + 
  geom_bar()+
  facet_wrap(~color)+
  ggtitle(" ") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0)
```

[image]

How can I  **Express the count of items per each group (cut) per each facet (color) as percentage**? So on the end I would obtain two full pie charts with the precentages written inside the pie chart.

Comment: Can you provide your dataset so that your example is reproducible? Also does this solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433798/how-to-change-y-axis-range-to-percent-from-number-in-barplot-with-r

Comment: @MichaelHarper I have added some data

Comment: Thanks for the data. it still wasn't truly reproducible as the head wasn't enough to reproduce the plot and the code contained lots of additional detail. I have updated your question to show how you could make it easier for others to help by 1) using a built in dataset (diamonds) and 2) removing additional code not related to the problem. Hope the example helps

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easiest to transform the data before you plot the graph. If we want to find the percentage of values within each group, we could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549731/finding-percentage-in-a-sub-group-using-group-by-and-summarise/29549927):

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(color, cut) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  group_by(color) %>%
  mutate(per=count/sum(count)) %>% 
  ungroup()

df
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   color cut       count    per
   <ord> <ord>     <int>  <dbl>
 1 D     Fair        163 0.0241
 2 D     Good        662 0.0977
 3 D     Very Good  1513 0.223 
 4 D     Premium    1603 0.237 
 5 D     Ideal      2834 0.418 
 6 E     Fair        224 0.0229
 7 E     Good        933 0.0952
 8 E     Very Good  2400 0.245 
 9 E     Premium    2337 0.239 
10 E     Ideal      3903 0.398
```

We can change the labels of the ggplot to percentage as below:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= "", y = per, fill=cut)) + 
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~color)+
  ggtitle(" ") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. Except, that it doe not work on my data, i get an error `no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"`

Comment: i just managed to run your code, it works, thanks! Is there a was to have the respective percentage written inside the pie chart, instead of 0%, 25%, 50%... ?

Comment: something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338757/adding-percentage-labels-on-pie-chart-in-r