# centering the label segment starting points for labelled pie charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I am trying to create a labelled pie chart using `ggrepel` based on a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41340766/7973626), but I can't seem to get the position of the labels correctly.

Ideally, I would like the segments that connect the labels to the portion of the pies to start in the middle of the pie for it to be more aesthetically pleasing. But this is not what I get, and I am not sure what I should be changing. I have tried setting `position = ggplot2::position_fill(vjust = 0.5)` in `ggrepel` call, but that doesn't help either.

## data

```r
# setup
set.seed(123)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(forcats)

# data
(df <- structure(
  list(
    cyl = structure(
      c(1L, 3L, 2L),
      .Label = c("8", "6", "4"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    counts = c(14L, 11L, 7L),
    perc = c(43.75, 34.375, 21.875),
    label = c("44%", "34%", "22%")
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -3L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   cyl   counts  perc label
#>   <fct>  <int> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 8         14  43.8 44%  
#> 2 4         11  34.4 34%  
#> 3 6          7  21.9 22%
```

## function

```r
# function
foo <- function(df, x) {
  ggplot2::ggplot(
    data = df,
    mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = "", y = counts, fill = forcats::fct_inorder({{ x }}))
  ) +
    ggplot2::geom_bar(
      stat = "identity",
      color = "black",
      width = 1,
      na.rm = TRUE
    ) +
    coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
    ggrepel::geom_label_repel(
      aes(label = label),
      show.legend = FALSE,
      nudge_x = 1
    ) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(title = rlang::as_name(rlang::ensym(x))))
}
```

## plot

```r
# plot
foo(df, cyl)
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the labels' stacked positions manually, instead of relying on ggplot. See if the following works for you:

```
foo <- function(df, x) {
  df$y.label <- 0.5 * df$counts + rev(cumsum(dplyr::lag(rev(df$counts), default = 0)))
  ggplot2::ggplot(
    data = df,
    mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = "", y = counts, fill = forcats::fct_inorder({{ x }}))
  ) +
    ggplot2::geom_col(
      color = "black",
      width = 1,
      na.rm = TRUE
    ) +
    coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
    ggrepel::geom_label_repel(
      aes(label = label, y = y.label),
      show.legend = FALSE,
      nudge_x = 1
    ) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(title = rlang::as_name(rlang::ensym(x))))
}

foo(df, cyl)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks, but I can't reproduce the output you are getting. This is what I see if I run your code: https://gist.github.com/IndrajeetPatil/c74b0e927e24e3f8b0717dfc46906e66#gistcomment-3384546

Comment: And I can't reproduce your output either. What do you get when you run `0.5 * df$counts + rev(cumsum(lag(rev(df$counts), default = 0)))`?

Comment: I see: `c(39.0, 23.5, 10.5)`.
I have also added session info to the gist in case that helps explain the discrepancy.

Comment: Oh I see. Please replace `lag` with `dplyr::lag`. (I have it loaded all the time till I forget it can conflict with `stats::lag`; will update my answer.)