# ggplot2 - piechart - value labels in reverse order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to match labels with my pie chart with ggplot2:

Code:

```
values=c(59,4,4,11,26)
labels=c("catA", "catB","catC","catD","catE")
pos = cumsum(values)- values/2
graph <- data.frame(values, labels,pos)

categoriesName="Access"
percent_str <- paste(round(graph$values / sum(graph$values) * 100,1), "%", sep="")

values <- data.frame(val = graph$values, Type = graph$labels, percent=percent_str, pos = graph$pos )

pie <- ggplot(values, aes(x = "", y = val, fill = Type)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1,stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(x= "", y=pos, label = val), size=3) 
pie + coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

Output:
[image: myoutput]

I read these topics, but without any success:

- [ggplot, facet, piechart: placing text in the middle of pie chart slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184188/ggplot-facet-piechart-placing-text-in-the-middle-of-pie-chart-slices)
- [R + ggplot2 => add labels on facet pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803460/r-ggplot2-add-labels-on-facet-pie-chart)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting in ggplot2 2.2.0, you can use `position_stack` with `vjust = .5` to center labels in stacked bars charts (and so pie charts).  You no longer need to calculate the position outside of ggplot2.  See the [NEWS](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md) for more details on these changes.

```
ggplot(values, aes(x = "", y = val, fill = Type)) + 
    geom_bar(width = 1,stat="identity") + 
    geom_text(aes(label = val), size=3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))  + 
    coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]